# Inline conditional rendering fail

Tags: react-native

I am trying to do an inline conditional rendering like the following:

```
 {var && <MyComponent />}
```

but it throws me this error:

`Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component`

However when I do it like this:

`{var !== '' && <MyComponent/ >}`
It works perfectly fine.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because empty string will be rendered in the component as it's a falsy value (because `&&` will return short-circuit value). And in react-native you can't render a string without wrapping it in `Text` component.